# Sum column values in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am workin on an evaluation system, and I need to retrieve the sum of the values of each answer given by the person that is evaluating.

This is the query I have now:

```
SELECT e.evaluado.nombre, e.evaluado.apellido, e.evaluador.nombre, e.evaluador.apellido,
(pd.puntaje*rc.escala.valor/SIZE(c.preguntaCerradaCollection)), e.evaluado.centroCosto.descripcion
FROM Criterio c, PreguntaCerrada p, Redacciones r, 
Evaluacion e, RespuestaPreguntaCerrada rc, Ponderacion pd, Escalas es
WHERE c.preguntaCerradaCollection = p
AND r.preguntaCerrada = p
AND r.instrumentos = e.idInstrumento
AND e.respuestaPreguntaCerradaCollection = rc
AND rc.preguntaCerrada = p
AND pd.criterio = c AND pd.instrumentos = e.idInstrumento
AND rc.escala = es
AND e.idPeriodo.idPeriodo = '2013-p1'
ORDER BY e.evaluado.nombre, e.evaluador.nombre, c.descripcion, e.evaluado.centroCosto
```

So, I have here, the Criteria, Questions, Answers, values of each Criteria, etc. This column is the one that gives back the numeric values of each answer:

```
(pd.puntaje*rc.escala.valor/SIZE(c.preguntaCerradaCollection))
```

But I need the total of those values for each employee because I need to know who were the 'n' best employees, or the worst.

If I use the SUM function, the query executor returns this:

Error 130: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

What could be the solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like your database cannot handle the SQL that is generated for the query, probably because size might require a sub query.  You might try creating an alias for size and using that in the calculation, but if that doesn't work you may have to return size separately and have the division performed in the application instead of on the database.

Comment: my opinion is that JPA is not the right tool for creating aggregate data. In many projects i have chosen a different but helpful solution: i create a sql VIEW with the aggregate data and then map an entity to it.